# How to limit Cassandra NTR queue size

Tags: cassandra

After upgrading to Cassandra 3.11.8 we are facing intermittent runaway NTR queue growth.
The NTR queue reaches a size of 5M at which point the node can't recover from the resulting GC overhead.
Having read [Improving Apache Cassandra’s Front Door and Backpressure](https://cassandra.apache.org/blog/Improving-Apache-Cassandras-Front-Door-and-Backpressure.html), we tried configuring `native_transport_max_concurrent_requests_in_bytes` to 1MB, assuming that would prevent the NTR queue from exploding. However, we still saw the NTR queue reach a size above 1M requests (so surely above a size of 1MB).

We have `-Dcassandra.max_queued_native_transport_requests=3072` vm argument set, and obviously that doesn't limit the queue size to 3072 requests. I'm also not sure if this setting still applies following [this change in 3.11.5](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-15013).
My questions are:

1. What is the right way to limit the NTR queue size in Cassandra 3.11.8?
2. If there is such a way, does it apply both to the inbound and outbound NTR queues? Or is the outbound queue really unbounded as stated [here](https://cassandra.apache.org/blog/Improving-Apache-Cassandras-Front-Door-and-Backpressure.html)?

Comment: Have you checked this one for Q1? https://support.datastax.com/s/article/High-blocked-NTR-count-during-increased-workload-on-Cassandra-node

Comment: @Astro this post suggests configuring cassandra.max_queued_native_transport_requests, I added our configuration of that parameter to the post (we are already using the value it suggests).